# Elementary forest question: meaning of calign, parent anchor and child anchor

Tags: forest

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    draw,
  }
  [center,calign=center
    [first, parent anchor=west, calign=child edge
      [ABC, child anchor=west]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

My understanding of the documentation is that the west of the third node (ABC) should be aligned with the west of the second node (first) because this is what `calign=child edge` is supposed to do (manual, 28):

> calign=child edge s-aligns the parent anchor of the parent and the
>   child anchor of the primary child.

But this is not how I imagined it:

[image: non-aligned]

As discussed in [chat with Gonzalo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22779062#22779062), [adding a sibling](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22779625#22779625) causes the alignments to work as expected:

```
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    draw,
  }
  [center,calign=center
    [first, parent anchor=west, calign=child edge
      [ABC, child anchor=west]
      []
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

[image: aligned]

Is this expected? Is it a bug? What am I missing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem described in the question is due to a bug in the package and a fixed version will be available from CTAN shortly. (Source: personal communication with package author.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I emailed the package author, Sašo Živanović, to ask whether this behaviour is intended or a bug.

Sašo has confirmed that it is a bug.

> ... it was a bug, child alignment was not run in nodes with a single child. ... I have fixed the bug and I'm posting the fixed version to ctan.

So a new version should make it to CTAN shortly and be available by updating TeX installations in a couple of days.

## EDIT

Here are the two trees whose code was given in the question, compiled with version 1.09 of `forest`.

The second 'control' tree with the additional child:

[image: control]

And the first test tree which previously showed the bug:

[image: corrected test tree with fixed package]

The version of the package with the fix is now available from CTAN and via TeX Live's `tlmgr`.

Comment: It's nice to finally know the answer. Thanks for writing to Sašo and for reporting his answer here.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina He said he's hoping to finish the new version this summer. It is nice to know I'm not nuts and horribly misconstruing the documentation ;).

Answer (score 3):

You have just defined the anchor of the connection (something like where to leave and where to reach...), not the anchor of the node it self.

Here you are:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={draw}
        [center%,calign=center
        [first, parent anchor=west, anchor=west, calign=child edge
        [ABC, child anchor=west, anchor=west]
        ]
        ]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

The manual is miss-leading though. I would report it.

Comment: Trying around to get the first two nodes centred, I got the feeling that there is something really buggy. `calign=midpoint` in the root destroys the alignment I just managed to get for the last two nodes.

Comment: That was precisely what led to this question. I was trying to construct the tree you created in an earlier `forest` question using a standard direction of growth and alignment. Not being able to led me here. If you think the manual is buggy, what do you think the description should be? Presumably, `calign=child edge` should do something different from `calign=child`. If it is not what it seems to say, what do you think it is meant to do? I guess I'm not convinced that using `anchor` here is supposed to be required...

Comment: @cfr me neither. If the manual was the fault, they should change "parent anchor" to "anchor" and "child anchor" to "anchor". But as I said, I think it is a real bug, not a bad description. `calign` should just effect the relation between current node and specified child. But it effects the whole forest here.

Comment: Also, the manual says that `anchor` should only have an observable effect when a node has a sibling which obviously isn't the case here.

Comment: I've updated the question: try adding a sibling and everything magically works! So I don't think that `parent anchor` and `child anchor` can be intended only as anchors `of the connection (something like where to leave and where to reach...)` but not to affect the alignment of the node itself ;).